# How can XMonad spawn a process with a specified working directory?

Tags: haskell, xmonad

I am using (and loving!) XMonad as a window manager. However, I'm not sure how to implement a keyboard shortcut that can `spawn` a new process/window with the working directory of the current window.

I'm thinking there are two parts to this problem: Determining the working directory of the currently-active window, and spawning a process with a given working directory.

For process spawning, I'm currently using a hack where I spawn `/bin/sh`, that `cd`'s to the desired location then starts the program. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

For determining the working directory of the current window, I have no idea how to do this. A quick search of `xmonad-contrib` didn't show anything, though I might have missed something. Is this an attribute that X makes available to the window manager? Maybe I could do something with the `/proc` tree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`spawn` already calls out to `/bin/sh`, so you can just shove the `cd` into the thing you spawn, as in `spawn "cd /very/good/directory && very-good-executable --very --good --arguments"`.

There is not even a reliable way to detect which process is associated with a given window -- and even if you could it may not even be running on this machine! -- let alone its working directory. But see also the `_NET_WM_PID` atom which is occasionally available and [this question on the Unix stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/94357/66679).

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how to access `_NET_WM_PID` from XMonad? I can see it in `xprop`, but there's no obvious Haskell function that gets it.

Comment: @ddulaney [getAtom](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-0.15/docs/XMonad-Core.html#v:getAtom)

Comment: Oh. Perfect! Thanks!